# Populating SelectList inside Popover AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a button in my AngularJS app and when you click the button a bootstrap popover appears that contains a select list. I'm trying to populate this select list from a list stored in my rootScope the the data is getting pulled into the popover but the select list is not been populated please see code below

Hard coded list stored in my rootScope

```
$rootScope.activeUsers = [{ userId: 1, userName: 'user1' }];
```

Popover HTML

```
                <div id="UsersPopover" style='display: none'>
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <h3>Please select a user.</h3>
                    <select ng-model="selectedUserId" ng-options="user.userId as user.userName for user in $root.activeUsers"></select>
                    <select ng-model="selectedUserId" ng-options="user.userId as user.userName for user in activeUsers"></select>
                    <select ng-model="selectedUserId" ng-options="user.userId as user.userName for user in $parent.activeUsers"></select>
                    {{$root.activeUsers}} // data appears {{activeUsers}} // data appears
                    <p>{{dirmessage}}</p>
                </div>
```

Button that opens the popover HTML

```
 <button class="btn btn-info" data-placement="bottom" mypopover popover-html="#UsersPopover" popover-placement="bottom">Click to open popover</button>
```

Popover Directive

```
app.directive('mypopover', function ($compile, $templateCache, $rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.activeUsers = $rootScope.activeUsers;

        scope.dirmessage = "the message has come through";

        var options = {
            trigger: 'click',
            html: true,
            placement: attrs.popoverPlacement,
            title: attrs.popoverTitle,
            content: function () {
                return $compile($(attrs.popoverHtml).html())(scope);

            }
        };
        $(element).popover(options);
    }
};
```

I've tried using the rootScope.activeUsers list directly to populate the select list as well as the activeUser list created in my directive and neither seem to work I don't get any errors and the list is just blank.

Please can someone help me fix this issue as I don't understand why any of the lists are not been populated as the data appears in the popover.

Comment: Of course, because you don't compile this HTML so Angular does noting about it. Either use AngularUI popover or make sure you compile HTML template before you pass it into popover.

Comment: Sorry my angular knowledge is failing me here... how do i compile the HTML template before passing it to the popover? please can you provide me with an example.

Comment: Actually, I can see you are compiling HTML before returning. So I don't understand what is the issue, looks like select is populated fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/W98qgNWYBtpteMnOimQi?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for creating a Plunkr i think ive found the issue thanks to your efforts... The problem may be because i'm using angular version 1.2.9 and i see you were using 1.4 however i cant change this as i need to support IE8  and angular version 1.2.9 is the latest version that does so. Im really stuck on this one how can i fix these select lists without upgrading angular?